# In typescript, what is the return type of a function that returns a void function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am adding return type values to my functions based on comments I have received 
in a code review and I don't know what to assign the return type to on this function:

```
function mysteryTypeFunction(): mysteryType {
    return function(): void {
        console.log('Doing some work!');
    };
}
```

What is the mysteryType for this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript will infer the return type, and the easiest way to find out what it infers is to hover over the symbol:

[image]

As we can see the return type is `() => void`. Which is a function signature of a function with no argument (the `()` part), that returns `void` (the `=> void` part).

```
function mysteryTypeFunction(): () => void {
    return function(): void {
        console.log('Doing some work!');
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be `() => void`

It's something that you can check by hovering over the function name itself.

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
mysteryTypeFunction(): () => void {
    return () => {
        console.log('Doing some work!');
    };
}
```